# Global notification banners (Like GameKit banners)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created a drop down banner system, like GameKits (When you get an achievement for example).

I can easily display the banner in one view with the code below. However, all my server code is stored in a singleton class, and would like to notify the user when something happens in there (regardless what view controller they are in). How would I go about doing this?

```
[self displayBannerWithTitle: @"title here"];
```

Thanks in advance